# What is the householder reflector's singular value?

Tags: linear-algebra

A householder reflector is $I-2ww^*$ where $ w$ is an unit vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $H = I- 2ww^*$ is hemitian, the singular values of $H$are just the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $H$.

Notice that if $u\perp w$, then $$Hu = u - 2ww^*u = u-2\langle u,w\rangle w = u$$

so $u$ is an eigenvector for $H$ with eigenvalue $1$. If you are working in $\mathbb{C}^n$, you can pick $n-1$ linearly independent vectors orthogonal to $v$ so the multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$ is at least $n-1$.

On the other hand, we have
$$Hw = w - 2ww^*w = w - 2\|w\|^2w = w-2w = -w$$

so $w$ is the eigenvector for $H$ with eigenvalue $-1$. Therefore, the only eigenvalues are $\pm 1$ so the desired singular value is $1$.

Comment: If I  calculate the eigenvalue like this:$|H-\lambda I|=|（1-\lambda ）I-2ww^*|=\begin{vmatrix}
1-\lambda & w^*\\
2w & I
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
1-\lambda+2w^*w & w^*\\
0 & I
\end{vmatrix}=0$，implying that $\lambda=3$, where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Kristy How did you get $$\det((1-\lambda) I - 2ww^*) = \begin{vmatrix} 1-\lambda & w^* \\ 2w & I\end{vmatrix}$$
It doesn't seem correct.